# numpy.gradient gives unexpected results

Tags: python, numpy

I have played around with numpy's gradient function for some more complex functions and I ran into issues when calculating the gradients for multivariate functions, so I created the following minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
def f(x,y):
    return x

x = np.linspace(-1,1,3)
y = x
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = f(xv, yv)
gradient = np.gradient(z,x,y)
print(gradient[0])
print(gradient[1])
```

Since the partial derivative of f with respect to x is 1 and the derivative with respect to y is 0, I expected that gradient[0], which I suppose is the gradient in the x direction for each mesh point, only contains 1s and vice versa gradient[1] only contains 0s. However, the output is

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]

[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

so the other way round... Why is that? The gradient in the x direction should basically say how much f changes when I increase x by 1 (so 1) and the gradient in the y direction should say how much f changes when I increase y by 1 (so 0). Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's a result of your meshgrid indexing. By default, meshgrid uses 'xy' indexing, which writes out the coordinates with y varying along rows, and x varying along columns. You want 'ij' indexing, where the first argument varies along the first axis, and the second argument varies along the second axis. That's what gradient expects.

Here's the relevant documentation:

> This function supports both indexing conventions through the indexing
> keyword argument. Giving the string ‘ij’ returns a meshgrid with
> matrix indexing, while ‘xy’ returns a meshgrid with Cartesian
> indexing. In the 2-D case with inputs of length M and N, the outputs
> are of shape (N, M) for ‘xy’ indexing and (M, N) for ‘ij’ indexing. In
> the 3-D case with inputs of length M, N and P, outputs are of shape
> (N, M, P) for ‘xy’ indexing and (M, N, P) for ‘ij’ indexing. The
> difference is illustrated by the following code snippet:
>
> ```
> xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
> for i in range(nx):
>     for j in range(ny):
>         # treat xv[i,j], yv[i,j]
>
> xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='xy')
> for i in range(nx):
>     for j in range(ny):
>         # treat xv[j,i], yv[j,i]
> ```

([Source](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html).)

Here's the fixed call to meshgrid.

```
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
```

Output:

```
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```